# Unable to click button using ng-click for AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, xpath

I am automating AngularJS application and need help for ng-click.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a ng-click="openProjectModal($event)">Create Project</a>
```

I tried the code below:

```
.//a[ng-click='openProjectModal($event)']
```

Using xpath is working, but i don't want to use xpath.

Answer (score 1):

since it is a link 1st think is you have to javascriptvoid(); to stop it redirection.
and in your controller you should have to write openProjectModal function

i.e

```
<a ng-click="javascriptvoid();openProjectModal($event)">Create Project</a>

$scope.openProjectModal = function(event){
  ............. 
  .............   
 }
```

it will might help you

Comment: I tried it's not working. please suggest me how to solve this